# HDTrans, It work on fedora 4 core but doen't work on fedora 20

Tags: fedora, portability

HDTrans is suited to Fedora 4 core, but I want to use it on latest version of Fedora.

So I compiled it on Fedora 20 version, however it makes errors like these.

```
[root@localhost HDTrans-0.4-1-tsr]# make
gcc  -M -fpic -O3 -Winline -finline-limit=30000 -DINLINE_EMITTERS  --param inline-    unit-growth=512 --param large-function-growth=2048 -funit-at-a-time -o .tmp.m decode.c
sed 's/\.o:/.new.o:/' .tmp.m > .decode.new.m
rm -f .tmp.m
gcc  -c -fpic -O3 -Winline -finline-limit=30000 -DINLINE_EMITTERS  --param inline-unit-growth=512 --param large-function-growth=2048 -funit-at-a-time -o decode.new.o decode.c

In file included from machine.h:38:0,
                 from decode.c:46:
signals.h:107:18: error: field ‘info’ has incomplete type
   struct siginfo info;
              ^
make: *** [decode.new.o] error 1
```

I think some standard libraries changed when version upgraded make problems.

So I copied all libraries in /usr/include on 4 core, and changed /usr/include on 20 version to those of 4 core.

But same errorrs are made.

What are the problems? how to fix it?

Is there anyone who could help me?

[SourceCode]http://srl.cs.jhu.edu/projects/HDTrans/HDTrans-0.4-1.tar.gz

Here is source code download link.

Answer (score -1):

As the error message suggests, the field 'info' has an incomplete type in the 'signals.h' file. This could be due to changes in the standard libraries between the two versions of Fedora.

To fix this issue, you could try updating the 'signals.h' file to a version that is compatible with Fedora 20. You could also try compiling the code on a different version of Fedora that is closer to Fedora 4 core.

Alternatively, you could try reaching out to the developers of HDTrans or the Fedora community for support in resolving this issue. They may be able to provide more specific recommendations or patches to fix the problem.